# How to transfer CuPy arrays to tensorflow

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, cupy

I'm using CuPy to generate some ground truth + network input data on the GPU, which I want to send to a TensorFlow network through the standard API:

```py
feed_dict = {
    network.Labels: labels,
    network.Network_Input: networkInput
}
```

However, TensorFlow 1.15 expects NumPy and not CuPy and I get this error:

```
File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 538, in asarray return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array
```

Trying to convert the CuPy arrays to NumPy arrays using

```py
labels = numpy.array(labels, dtype=np.float)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: object __array__ method not producing an array
```

Is there a way to pass CuPy data to tensorflow ?

Answer (score 2):

DLPack tensor structure is now supported in Tensorflow 2 in the [`tf.experimental.dlpack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/experimental/dlpack) package.

You can find the howto usage in this repo: https://github.com/VoVAllen/tf-dlpack#cupy---tensorflow

```
# pip install numba numpy
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

# NumPy - CPU Array
cpu_arr = np.random.rand(10_000, 10_000)

# Use Numba to move to GPU
numba_gpu_arr = cuda.to_device(cpu_arr)

# Use CuPy's asarray function and toDlpack to create DLPack capsule. There are multiple other ways to do this (i.e. PyTorch Utils)
dlpack_arr = cp.asarray(numba_gpu_arr).toDlpack()

# Migrate from Numba, used for custom CUDA JIT kernels to PyTorch
tf_tensor = tfdlpack.from_dlpack(dlpack_arr)

# Confirm TF tensor is on GPU
print(tf_tensor.device)

# Use `tfdlpack` to migrate back to Numba
dlpack_capsule = tfdlpack.to_dlpack(tf_tensor)
numba_arr = cuda.to_device(cp.fromDlpack(dlpack_capsule))
```

Answer (score -1):

To copy CuPy array (on GPU) to NumPy array (on CPU), use `cupy.asnumpy(arr)` or `arr.get()`.

https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/latest/reference/ndarray.html#conversion-to-from-numpy-arrays

Comment: It seems CuPy has a special API to PyTorch, allowing to convert CuPy arrays to PyTorch tensors on the GPU, without going through NumPy on the CPU. However, such a support for TensorFlow is missing :-(

Comment: CuPy supports standard protocols (DLPack and cuda_array_interface) but TF does not. It seems there are some discussions ongoing: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24453 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/29039